# How do I prevent resetting Session timeout when UpdatePanel's content is refreshed by a Timer event?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

We have several pages in our ASP.net Ajax application which auto refresh the UpdatePanels contents based on a timer event but the problem is that we have a requirement to timeout the web session and the auto refresh is preventing that.

Is there a way to prevent the timer postback event from modifying the web session or any other alternate solution to allow the web session to timeout while auto refreshing the UpdatePanel contents?

Here is an example to illustrate this problem.  I set the session timeout to 3 minutes and have a timer in the UpdatePanel that ticks every minute and modifies the contents of the UpdatePanel based on the current state.  After logging in, I navigate to this page and do nothing for 5 minutes and then try and click on another page and I am still logged in since the session didn't time out.

Answer (score 2):

You may track the activity of the user on the client side. If there is no mouse move etc. you could log the user out using the `Sys.Services.AuthenticationService` class (part of Microsoft AJAX Library 1.0). You could pop a confirmation before you do the actual log out, so that the user may cancel it if he is present. When logged out you could pop a message to the user saying that he was automatically logged out because of inactivity.

How my solution would solve your scenario:

You set the session timeout to 3 minutes and have a timer in the UpdatePanel that ticks every minute and modifies the contents of the UpdatePanel based on the current state. After logging in, you navigate to this page and do nothing. After 3 minutes of no activity you pop a confirmation to the user asking him to cancel automatic log out using the `Sys.Services.AuthenticationService`. If the user still takes no action you log him out after a few seconds. You pop a "logged out message" that the user will see when he returns to the browser after 5 minutes. When he then click on another page he is not logged in.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you are saying but I was hoping for a simpler solution. To paraphrase, since the session is not timing out due to the Timer event postback, you suggest that I keep track of how long the user has been inactive relying on something other than session timeout.  It could even piggyback on the Timer refresh event.  My only concern is that it seems like I would end up having to manually handle session timeout.

Comment: Sys.Services.AuthenticationService is part of Microsoft AJAX Library 1.0. It is a JavaScript library. So what I am saying is that you keep track of user activity on the client side. Mouse move etc... You log the user out with a JavaScript call to the logout function on the Sys.Services.AuthenticationService object.

Comment: For my case, invalidating the session would be required rather than using Sys.Services.AuthenticationService since the login mechanism is custom and based on the session.  I believe I have a solution that does not involve any javascript which is preferable but I need to test it out.  Thanks for your answer and comment as it got me to think about this problem in a new way that led to my proposed solution.