# Will Session timeout occur if i am using a timer and loading a control page constantly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session-timeout

I am constantly uploading a user control , after putting it in a update panel.Using javascript to reload the update panel the user control is in , will it stop the session time out?Or does that depend on user involvement etc?

Code is below:

javascript function  :

```
function checkCallbackConstantly() {


    __doPostBack('<%=updateCallbacks.ClientID %>', '');

    setTimeout('checkCallbackConstantly()', 1000);
}

setTimeout('checkCallbackConstantly()', 10000);
```

And :

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="updateCallbacks">
       <ContentTemplate>

            <t1:topNav   ID="topNav1" runat="server"  />

       </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And on the control page , i am playing with session ,so kindly let me know.

Thank you

Comment: I think this might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770594/how-do-i-prevent-resetting-session-timeout-when-updatepanels-content-is-refresh

Comment: @user1016740 Thank you , the info was helpful

Comment: Thank you all for your answer , but i marked the one which provided me with answer and some facts related to my approach.

Thank you all once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you implement will make the session "endless" but BEWARE that [IIS recycles the app pool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753179%28WS.10%29.aspx) regularely (and sometimes also unexpectedly)... IF your sessions are not persisted this will "expire" all currently active sessions at once since all session-related information stored in memory will be lost when such a recycling happens!

Comment: oh that's bad ... But is there any other way ? I am currently getting some info from the db and storing in session , and then keep checking it constantly (the info basically are appointment dates). So i keep checking if they match current date, a pop up appears, Kindly let me know if there is any other better way to do this

Comment: @confusedMind there are several options... basically make your session management persitent and/or use a Windows Service as session provider and/or store your session information the DB etc.

Comment: Marking this as answer as it not only provides the answer but also made me aware of other things that i might face.

THank you all

Answer (score 1):

Every request will extend the session time of the user who does the request.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net uses sliding session expiration since last request to server in with given session ID.

So in your case session state will not expire (with default settings) since you are making request to server before session have chance to expire.

Comment: Thank you also please let me know will this apply to all the session variable,or just the one i am using again.:)

Comment: All Session variable (whole Session object). There is no tracking of what properties you store in Session by ASP.Net, just the fact that you have a request that needs Session.

Answer (score 0):

Visit

http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/06/26/how-to-refresh-an-updatepanel-from-javascript.aspx